# npm install -g eas-cli fails

Tags: react-native, expo

I am a newbie to react-native and would like to start developing a react-native app.
I could have started developing by react-native-cli, but I heard there was something called Expo and a way to open an initial app with expo-cli.

I copied and pasted this code `npm install -g eas-cli`, but it gave me a huge long error message I put its screenshot below.

I have no idea about the system?? inside my computer.

I would be so grateful if anyone gives me a possible solution.

Thanks for your valuable time^^

=========== Edit ===========
So I read the first comment, and run this command on my Mac `brew install nvm`. It worked nicely and looked for more information for what to do from this point. Then I ran this command `mkdir ~/.nvm`, and I am stack now. I created a directory called .nvm, but so what from now??

Thanks a lot for taking your time to help me!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably installed `npm` using `sudo`, or something like that.

I would recommend to install `npm` using `nvm`. It usually removes all those errors.